# System.Web.Services namespace in .net core

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard

I am creating proxy class for SOAP services dynamically where I need `System.Web.Services` namespace and I am using .NET 5(Core).
I am not able to find `System.Web.Services` namespace in .NET 5, so is it deprecated or moved to another namespace? How can I use classes of `System.Web.Services` namespace in .NET 5.

Below is code where I need this namespace:

```
 public class DynamicWSProxy: IDynamicWSProxy
{
    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Unrestricted = true)]
    public object CallWebService(string webServiceAsmxUrl, string serviceName, string methodName, object[] args)
    {
        System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

        // Connect To the web service
        System.IO.Stream stream = client.OpenRead(webServiceAsmxUrl + "?wsdl");

        // Now read the WSDL file describing a service.
        ServiceDescription description = ServiceDescription.Read(stream);

        ///// LOAD THE DOM /////////

        // Initialize a service description importer.

        ServiceDescriptionImporter importer = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();
        importer.ProtocolName = "Soap12"; // Use SOAP 1.2.
        importer.AddServiceDescription(description, null, null);

        // Generate a proxy client.
        importer.Style = ServiceDescriptionImportStyle.Client;

        // Generate properties to represent primitive values.
        importer.CodeGenerationOptions = System.Xml.Serialization.CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties;

        // Initialize a Code-DOM tree into which we will import the service.
        CodeNamespace nmspace = new CodeNamespace();
        CodeCompileUnit unit1 = new CodeCompileUnit();
        unit1.Namespaces.Add(nmspace);

        // Import the service into the Code-DOM tree. This creates proxy code that uses the service.
        ServiceDescriptionImportWarnings warning = importer.Import(nmspace, unit1);

        if (warning == 0) // If zero then we are good to go
        {

            // Generate the proxy code
            CodeDomProvider provider1 = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

            // Compile the assembly proxy with the appropriate references
            string[] assemblyReferences = new string[5] { "System.dll", "System.Web.Services.dll", "System.Web.dll", "System.Xml.dll", "System.Data.dll" };

            CompilerParameters parms = new CompilerParameters(assemblyReferences);

            CompilerResults results = provider1.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parms, unit1);

            // Check For Errors
            if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (CompilerError oops in results.Errors)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("========Compiler error============");
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(oops.ErrorText);
                }
                throw new System.Exception("Compile Error Occured calling webservice. Check Debug ouput window.");
            }

            // Finally, Invoke the web service method

            object wsvcClass = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(serviceName, true);

            MethodInfo mi = wsvcClass.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);

            return mi.Invoke(wsvcClass, args);

        }

        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`System.Web.Services` is a predecessor of WCF. Since even the mighty WCF is considered deprecated on the server side, do not expect `System.Web.Services` to be available in .NET Core or the concrete App Model ASP.NET Core 1.0. Their namespaces even start with `Microsoft.AspNetCore`. SOAP is considered deprecated in favor of REST and JSON. Microsoft will tell you: Use the .NET Framework but not .NET Core.