# Could not find file or assembly System.Web.Services

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, sharepoint

I am trying to execute the below code to retrieve details from Sharepoint using C#. It is giving error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file
> specified.'

```
using (ClientContext spcontext = new ClientContext("siteURL"))
{
     spcontext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
     spcontext.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = new FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo("UserName","Password");
     spcontext.Load(spcontext.Web, w => w.Title, w => w.ServerRelativeUrl, w => w.Lists);
     spcontext.ExecuteQuery();
     Console.WriteLine(spcontext.Web.ServerRelativeUrl);
}
```

My application is ASP.NET Core 3.1.

Comment: check you config file for "System.Web.Services", see if its there or not or if the version is different

Comment: @AHMEDSAJJAD Which config file? I see only appsettings.json

Comment: check appsettings

Comment: @AHMEDSAJJAD There is no details of System.Web.Services in that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.Web.Services namespace in .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36544471/system-web-services-namespace-in-net-core)

Answer (score 2):

System.Web.Services does not exist on .NET Core.

Comment: In that case what is the solution? Any other Sharepoint library which works with .NET Core ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any. Maybe keep it in a .NET Framework process and call it from your .NET Core process over HTTP.

Comment: You mean I need to change the target framework to .NET 4 or rewrite the application in .NET Framework 4 ?

Comment: In the answer suggested here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62918952/alternative-save-openbinarydirect-methods-for-csom-for-sharepoint-online/62930801#62930801, I am not getting AuthenticationManager class and GetContext method. By added reference to OfficePnPCore, I got AuthenticationManager but there is no GetContext.