# Options to Salesforce SOAP API "System.Web.Service" namespace issue for .NET 6

Tags: c#, soap, salesforce, .net-6.0

I have C# 4.5 microservice application where Salesforce SOAP is used using SforceService.cs file for api calls. Now we are in process of upgrading the service to .net 6.
after upgrading the service with upgrade tool. project containing SforceService.cs started giving
error related "System.Web.Service" namespace not present in Net 6.
As somebody mentioned here
[System.Web.Services namespace in .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36544471/system-web-services-namespace-in-net-core)

I tried to regenerate the SforceService.cs file again using wsdl file by referring https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008sFBIAY
but generated class does not have the SforceService Object as somebody mentioned here
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=9062I000000R46dQAC

Please suggest how we can tackle this situation?
Thanks